# How change legend icons size on leaflet map generated using QGIS2WEB plugin?

Tags: qgis, leaflet, qgis-plugins, web-mapping, qgis2web

I need to know how to change size of icons from the leaflet web map legend generated using qgis2web plugin. Is there any icon size information inside code which I can change to larger number? I have searched for it in the map folder, but with no success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The exported images are in the `legend` folder in your export folder. The code which includes them is in `index.html`. Open that in a text editor, and find:

```
<img src="legend/LAYERNAME_0.png" />
```

where LAYERNAME is the name of the layer this legend icon applies to. Add size info like this:

```
<img src="legend/LAYERNAME_0.png" width="50" height="50" />
```

Width and height are in pixels.